# Format Timestamp to Round-trip date/time pattern in php

Tags: php, date, time

how to format a timestamp to  Round-trip date/time pattern?

is there any in built function available?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Round-trip date/time pattern

Comment: i dont know what is the format of  Round-trip date/time pattern, but it is a standard

Comment: I still don't understand. You have posted no example. Maybe someone else will be able to understand or guess what you mean.

Comment: i find the format is like  2016-04-14T15:17:56.074+01:00